# Convert SQL Statement to LINQ VS2010

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, linqer

I would appreciate help in converting the following sql statement to linq:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        *,
        rn = row_number() over (partition by ClientId order by VisitId)
    from
        Visit
) activityWithRn
inner join vw_MasterView on  vw_MasterView.VisitId = activityWithRn.VisitId
where activityWithRn.rn =3
```

When I use Linqer (a wonderful program) I get the following error:

```
SQL cannot be converted to LINQ: Field [rn = row_number() over (partition by ClientId order by VisitId)] not found in the current Data Context.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't mention which ORM you're using, but if you're using entity framework you can just keep using the SQL with ExecuteStoreQuery - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any corresponding feature in LINQ for `row_number() over`, other than using `Skip...Take`:

```
var q = (from v in Visit
            join mv in vw_MasterView on v.VisitId equals mv.VisitId 
            orderby v.VisitId
            select v).Skip(2).Take(1);
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this error:  'Join' not found.
The name 'vw_MasterView' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I would expect you already have a set (a collection or a an object set in your object / data context) which matches the SQL view `vw_MasterView`. How would the tool create this object for you?

Comment: I use Linqer to test, it is conected to the data context.

Comment: Maybe you need to prefix both sets (`Visit` and `vw_MaterView`) with the context variable name. Something like `dc.Visit` and `dc.vw_MasterView`. I don't have Linqer to test, sorry.